# Do not load the Division if using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying **NOT** to load the **Division** using JS, but it loads and then remove the content. 
I do not want it, tried **remove()** and **hide()** both working like hiding it after loading.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 700) {
    $('.desktop-only').remove();
  } else {
    $('.mobile-only').remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="desktop-only">
  <a class="GAds" href="https://ads.google.com">
    <img height="80" width="80" class="img-ads" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
    <div class="ads">
      Mobile Google Ads
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="mobile-only">
  <a class="GAds" href="https://ads.google.com">
    <img height="80" width="80" class="img-ads" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
    <div class="ads">
      Desktop Google Ads
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a Catch 22. The element has to exist before you can target it with javascript to remove it. Perhaps you want to do the reverse and hide with css and show the appropriate one instead?

Comment: @charlietfl any way like loading whole the Division within the JS code? Can it be answered?

Comment: Is this just a visual display problem or more involved such as not wanting images to load?

Comment: @charlietfl like do not want to load the Ads if mobile, but it loads and then remove which is a bit bad

Comment: Not enough known about how the ads work without you providing a [mre]

Comment: @charlietfl I added the example, Desk and Mobile ads both loading and Mobile is then disappearing

Comment: Why not using CSS media queries instead of Javascript?

Comment: Those images appear identical so using media query css should solve the problem as there doesn't seem to be a resource loading problem

Comment: @CherryDT Css also loads the content and make it display none

Comment: @RiyaSingh it's unclear what you want then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to `.remove()` an object it first needs to be loaded into the DOM and recognizable. Elements are viewable as the page is loading. However, `$(document).ready()` never fires until the page is done loading. Hence why you can see both for a few seconds before the page is done loading.
You have two main options here:

## Option 1

The first one is to set both of the ads to be hidden `style="display: hidden;"` and then remove the hidden tag once the page is loaded: `$('.class').css('display','');`.

## Option 2

Or, since both "ad types" only have one single element which is different between the two. You can have one, empty, element loaded in and append the data you want to it once the page loads. This one takes a bit more work.

> HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ad-container">
</div>
```

> JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var adTypeName = "";
  if ($(window).width() <= 700) {
    adTypeName = "Desktop Google Ads";
  } else {
    adTypeName = "Mobile Google Ads";
  }
  $('.ad-container').html('\
  <a class="GAds" href="https://ads.google.com">\
    <img height="80" width="80" class="img-ads" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532400-2682810df593?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">\
    <div class="ads">\
      '+adTypeName+'\
    </div>\
  </a>');
});
```

Essentually we are just taking out code block and depending on the screen size we are saying whether it's "Desktop Google Ads" or "Mobile Google Ads". Then we insert the entire code block into the div element called `.ad-container`.

You would most likely want to use Option 1 however I figured I'd provide option 2 in-case for some reason you would need that instead? But I would only choose 2 over 1 if I had a very specific reason for doing so.